# What's the meaning of dotTrace's numbers in Line-By-Line profiling?

Tags: user-interface, profiler, dottrace, line-by-line

[image]

What do those numbers mean exactly? Times the line was hit? Microseconds per invocation? Or what?

Also, what do the 'progress-bars' behind the numbers mean? They aren't even proportional to the numbers, so I'm really confused.

Answer (score 2):

Dear Stefan,
These numbers represent the number of calls to the corresponding statements. Please note, that a single C# construct may correspond to several statements. Thus for example "for" loop contains 3 statements.
The number is surrounded with a rectangle if this statement takes a significant amount of time an the ratio of this time is painted with light-blue inside the rectangle.

best wishes, Michael

Answer (score 0):

And don't forget the graph which is a visual indicator of time spent relative to the rest of the execution code.